# Wordpress Access WP-Admin when installed in a sub directory

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have just taken over managing a website for a client from their previous developer. I have been given a copy of all the files and the database.

I am in the process of trying to set up the website on our Xampp server. Whilst I have got the site mostly working I am struggling to access wp-admin.

The site is installed in a subdirectory in C:\Xampp\htdocs\example.com\
It is also a multi Wordpress site which I have never managed before.

While the frontend of the site is mostly working, apart from some urls which need updating. When I go to wp-admin, I am taken to http://127.0.0.1/wp-admin, instead of http://127.0.0.1/example.com/wp-admin

I have gone through the database and updated the domain and url for the website in all tables that I can find require this information:

```
wp_site - domain: 127.0.0.1, path: /example.com/
wp_sitemeta - siteurl: http://127.0.0.1/example.com/
wp_blogs - domain: 127.0.0.1, path: /example.com/
wp_options - siteurl: http://127.0.0.1/example.com/, home: http://127.0.0.1/example.com/
```

I have also updated wp-config with the correct database settings, and I have set these correctly:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '127.0.0.1');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/example.com/');
```

Is there an option I am missing in the database I need to set, have I set something incorrectly. I have looked at rewrites in htaccess and can't see anything that could be affecting it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following to your config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://127.0.0.1/example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://127.0.0.1/example.com' );
```

if this is not working, try to take a backup of your `.htaccess` file, then remove it and flush your permalinks, to do so, you'd have to add this

```
add_action('init', 'custom_flush_rewriterules');
function custom_flush_rewriterules(){
   global $wp_rewrite; 
   $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/'); 
   update_option( "rewrite_rules", FALSE ); 
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );
}
```

Then open the site once, make sure `.htaccess` is created and remove the above code

Comment: No luck from adding those settings, or deleting  the .htaccess. How can I save the permalinks, without being able to get into admin? 127.0.0.1/wp-admin is just a 404, I should have mentioned. Can I do it through the database somehow?

Comment: I've figured it out, there is a htaccess entry forcing a trailing slash to wp-admin. If it isn't there it redirects to the base url, otherwise works correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, refreshing the `.htaccess` should solve the issue for you, I added code to force the refresh.